# Цвета в colors.xml в зависимости от значения из Preference

Tags: android, xml, android-preferences, android-selector

У меня в `PrefActivity` есть `ListPreference` с двумя возможными строковыми значениями. Также есть файл `colors.xml`, где описаны некоторые цвета, которые впоследствии используются в остальных стилевых файлах.

Вопрос: как в зависимости от значения из `Preference` в `colors.xml` изменить цвета? Есть подозрение, что нужно использовать `selector`, но я точно не знаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Задача в один ход не решается: selector ничего не знает про preferences. Вам придется кодить: достать выбранное значение из preferences, подобрать соответствующее ему значение цвета или его id в R.color, задать этот цвет соответствующему элементу.

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Если таких мест будет много, то нужно будет сделать класс-хелпер для работы с цветом. Или сделать кастомную вьюху, в которую спрятать работу с цветом.

Comment: Можно поподробней пункт "Если таких мест будет много"?

Comment: Ну, много, в простом бытовом смысле. Вы замечаете, что этот setBackgoundColor копипастите в коде уже тридцатый раз. Это уже давно много. :) По вопросу же непонятн, как у вас устроен интерфейс, и сколько надо менять цветов.

Comment: Видимо, вы неправильно поняли мой комментарий) Я имел ввиду поподробней рассказать про реализацию класса-хелпера или что вы подразумеваете под "кастомной вьюхой", так как для каждого элемента каждого активити отдельно прописывать цвет фона слишком геморно.